# Obtain analytical data for a specific video within a date range

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

So after scouring the youtube API, and thinking that this may not be possible, I'll give a last try here.

In a nutshell, I am trying to obtain analytical data from youtube's analytics's API for specific videos for a date range (by day if possible). I've found ways to get the channel data that the video reside in, but I have been unable to find how to ontain the specific video data itself. Assuming it exists in v3 that is.

Anyone had any luck with this kind of task at all? Has this feature been developed for v3 as of yet?

Comment: First, what particular data are you trying to obtain? You say "the specific video data itself" - are you trying to download the video? Second, are you asking for the selection procedure for "specific videos for a date range" as well? If yes, then please be more specific on this one too.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I'm after the analytical data for particular videos, for example their likes, views, comments, etc... in a certain date range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Channel Reports](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/channel_reports) is the API to retrieve video metrics. It can [filter by video, by country, by lead (for some fields)](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/channel_reports#Filters) and [accepts timespan and data aggregation granularity](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/dimsmets/dims). In brief, [Available Reports](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/content_owner_reports#Reports) lists all the valid query parameter combinations.
- Individual comments [can be retrieved with v2 Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_comments) - together with their dates.